# xslt 1.0 grouping on 3 elements issue

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

i was hoping someone could help me with this problem:
I have a xml that I need to "convert" into a different structure and group the data using 3 elements.
I am able to to group the data, except in case where OpportunityContactRole/records/Contact is repeating, so basically if you look at the input I am missing the second contact in the output.

thanks in advance for your help.

Structure of the document:

```
<QueryResult>
<done>true</done>
<records type="Opportunity" url="/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Opportunity/0062900000CE9pyAAD">
    <Id>0062900000CE9pyAAD</Id>
    <Amount>2500.0</Amount>
    <Name>MyFirstOpportunity</Name>
    <StageName>2 - Specification</StageName>
    <CloseDate>2020-12-31</CloseDate>
    <Project_State__c>tx</Project_State__c>
    <Sub_Project_Type__c>Education</Sub_Project_Type__c>
    <Project_Type__c>Commercial</Project_Type__c>
    <Project_City__c>dallas</Project_City__c>
    <OpportunityContactRoles>
        <done>true</done>
        <records type="OpportunityContactRole" url="/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/OpportunityContactRole/00K29000002hWqhEAE">
            <Role>Evaluator</Role>
            <IsPrimary>false</IsPrimary>
            <Contact type="Contact" url="/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Contact/0030G00002VAY4wQAH">
                <Name>Lynn Tyson</Name>
                <Title>manager</Title>
                <FirstName>Lynn</FirstName>
                <LastName>Tyson</LastName>
                <Email>ltyson@email.com</Email>
            </Contact>
        </records>
        <records type="OpportunityContactRole" url="/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/OpportunityContactRole/00K29000002hWqIEAU">
            <IsPrimary>false</IsPrimary>
            <Contact type="Contact" url="/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Contact/0032900000XDPMZAA5">
                <Name>Cynthia Mohawk</Name>
                <FirstName>Cynthia</FirstName>
                <LastName>Mohawk</LastName>
                <Email>cynthiam@test.com</Email>
                <Phone>2145455555</Phone>
            </Contact>
        </records>
        <totalSize>2</totalSize>
    </OpportunityContactRoles>
    <CreatedDate>2020-09-21T17:47:17.000Z</CreatedDate>
    <Owner type="User" url="/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/User/005F0000001pfgsIAA">
        <Name>Dee Carson</Name>
        <FirstName>Dee</FirstName>
        <LastName>Carson</LastName>
        <Email>demetria_carson@test.com</Email>
    </Owner>
    <Account type="Account" url="/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Account/0010G00001vET2OQAW">
        <Name>BGM INSTALATION INC</Name>
        <DW_ID__c>389172002</DW_ID__c>
        <Owner type="User" url="/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/User/0050G000008GFmPQAW">
            <Name>David Santibanez</Name>
            <FirstName>David</FirstName>
            <LastName>Santibanez</LastName>
            <Email>david.santibanez@email.com.invalid</Email>
        </Owner>
        <ShippingCity>LOMITA</ShippingCity>
        <ShippingState>CA</ShippingState>
    </Account>
</records>
<records type="Opportunity" url="/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Opportunity/0060G00000mB6ggQAC">
    <Id>0060G00000mB6ggQAC</Id>
    <Amount>25000.0</Amount>
    <Name>Tjx Marlboro</Name>
    <StageName>2 - Specification</StageName>
    <CloseDate>2020-12-18</CloseDate>
    <Project_State__c>MA</Project_State__c>
    <Sub_Project_Type__c>Retail</Sub_Project_Type__c>
    <Project_Type__c>Commercial</Project_Type__c>
    <Project_City__c>Marlboro</Project_City__c>
    <CreatedDate>2016-10-19T21:04:09.000Z</CreatedDate>
    <Owner type="User" url="/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/User/005A00000012ASUIA2">
        <Name>Elisa Franklin</Name>
        <FirstName>Elisa</FirstName>
        <LastName>Franklin</LastName>
        <Email>elisa.franklin@email.com.invalid</Email>
    </Owner>
    <Account type="Account" url="/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Account/001F000000koRGyIAM">
        <Name>smma</Name>
        <Owner type="User" url="/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/User/005A00000012ASUIA2">
            <Name>Elisa Franklin</Name>
            <FirstName>Elisa</FirstName>
            <LastName>Franklin</LastName>
            <Email>elisa.franklin@email2.com.invalid</Email>
        </Owner>
        <ShippingCity>cambridge</ShippingCity>
        <ShippingState>MA</ShippingState>
    </Account>
</records>
<totalSize>1</totalSize>
```

output format:

```
<Aitor>
    <Accounts>
        <Account>
            <LegacyAccountId>389172002</LegacyAccountId>
            <Name>BGM INSTALATION INC</Name>
            <City>LOMITA</City>
            <OwnerEmail/>
            <State>CA</State>
            <UserName>David Santibanez</UserName>
            <UserFirstName>David</UserFirstName>
            <UserLastName>Santibanez</UserLastName>
            <UserEmail>david.santibanez@email.com.invalid</UserEmail>
            <UserPhone/>
            <Contacts>
                <Contact>
                    <Role>Evaluator</Role>
                    <IsPrimary>false</IsPrimary>
                    <Name>Lynn Tyson</Name>
                    <FirstName>Lynn</FirstName>
                    <LastName>Tyson</LastName>
                    <Email>ltyson@email.com</Email>
                    <Phone>2145455555</Phone>
                    <Opportunities>
                        <Opportunity>
                            <Id>0062900000CE9pyAAD</Id>
                            <Name>MyFirstOpportunity</Name>
                            <CreatedDate>2020-09-21T17:47:17.000Z</CreatedDate>
                            <Amount>2500.0</Amount>
                            <StageName>2 - Specification</StageName>
                            <ClosedDate>2020-12-31</ClosedDate>
                            <ProjectState>tx</ProjectState>
                            <SubProjectType>Education</SubProjectType>
                            <ProjectType>Commercial</ProjectType>
                            <ProjectCity>dallas</ProjectCity>
                        </Opportunity>
                    </Opportunities>
                </Contact>
            </Contacts>
        </Account>
        <Account>
            <LegacyAccountId/>
            <Name>smma</Name>
            <City>cambridge</City>
            <OwnerEmail/>
            <State>MA</State>
            <UserName>Elisa Franklin</UserName>
            <UserFirstName>Elisa</UserFirstName>
            <UserLastName>Franklin</UserLastName>
            <UserEmail>elisa.franklin@email.com.invalid</UserEmail>
            <UserPhone/>
            <Contacts>
                <Contact>
                    <Role/>
                    <IsPrimary/>
                    <Name>No Contact</Name>
                    <FirstName>No Contact</FirstName>
                    <LastName>No Contact</LastName>
                    <Email>No Contact</Email>
                    <Phone>No Contact</Phone>
                    <Opportunities>
                        <Opportunity>
                            <Id>0060G00000mB6ggQAC</Id>
                            <Name>Tjx Marlboro</Name>
                            <CreatedDate>2016-10-19T21:04:09.000Z</CreatedDate>
                            <Amount>25000.0</Amount>
                            <StageName>2 - Specification</StageName>
                            <ClosedDate>2020-12-18</ClosedDate>
                            <ProjectState>MA</ProjectState>
                            <SubProjectType>Retail</SubProjectType>
                            <ProjectType>Commercial</ProjectType>
                            <ProjectCity>Marlboro</ProjectCity>
                        </Opportunity>
                    </Opportunities>
                </Contact>
            </Contacts>
        </Account>
    </Accounts>
</Aitor>
```

My xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0"/>
    <xsl:key name="account" match="records" use="Account/@url"/>
    <xsl:key name="contact2" match="records" use="concat(Account/@url, '|', OpportunityContactRoles/records/Contact/@url)"/>
    <xsl:key name="recordid3" match="records" use="concat(Account/@url, '|', OpportunityContactRoles/records/Contact/@url, '|', Id)"/>
    <xsl:key name="owner" match="records" use="concat(Account/@url, '|', Owner/@url)"/>
    <xsl:key name="recordid" match="records" use="concat(Account/@url, '|', Owner/@url, '|', Id)"/>
    <xsl:key name="account2" match="records/OpportunityContactRoles/records" use="../../Account/@url"/>
    <xsl:key name="contact" match="records/OpportunityContactRoles/records" use="concat(Contact/@url, '|', ../../Account/@url)"/>
    <xsl:key name="recordid2" match="records/OpportunityContactRoles/records" use="concat(Contact/@url, '|', ../../Account/@url, '|', ../../Id)"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/QueryResult"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/QueryResult">
        <Aitor>
            <Accounts>
                <xsl:for-each select="//records[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('account', Account/@url)[1])]">
                    <Account>
                        <LegacyAccountId>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Account/DW_ID__c/text()"/>
                        </LegacyAccountId>
                        <Name>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Account/Name/text()"/>
                        </Name>
                        <City>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Account/ShippingCity/text()"/>
                        </City>
                        <OwnerEmail> </OwnerEmail>
                        <State>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Account/ShippingState/text()"/>
                        </State>
                        <UserName>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Account/Owner/Name/text()"/>
                        </UserName>
                        <UserFirstName>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Account/Owner/FirstName/text()"/>
                        </UserFirstName>
                        <UserLastName>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Account/Owner/LastName/text()"/>
                        </UserLastName>
                        <UserEmail>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Account/Owner/Email/text()"/>
                        </UserEmail>
                        <UserPhone>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Account/Owner/Phone/text()"/>
                        </UserPhone>
                        <Contacts>
                            <xsl:for-each select="key('account', Account/@url)[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('contact2',concat(Account/@url, '|', OpportunityContactRoles/records/Contact/@url))[1])]">
                                <Contact>
                                    <Role>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="OpportunityContactRoles/records/Role/text()"/>
                                    </Role>
                                    <IsPrimary>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="OpportunityContactRoles/records/IsPrimary/text()"/>
                                    </IsPrimary>
                                    <Name>
                                        <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when test="OpportunityContactRoles/records/Contact">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="OpportunityContactRoles/records/Contact/Name/text()"/>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="'No Contact'"/>
                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                                    </Name>
                                    <FirstName>
                                        <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when test="OpportunityContactRoles/records/Contact">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="OpportunityContactRoles/records/Contact/FirstName/text()"/>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="'No Contact'"/>
                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                                    </FirstName>
                                    <LastName>
                                        <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when test="OpportunityContactRoles/records/Contact">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="OpportunityContactRoles/records/Contact/LastName/text()"/>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="'No Contact'"/>
                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                                    </LastName>
                                    <Email>
                                        <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when test="OpportunityContactRoles/records/Contact">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="OpportunityContactRoles/records/Contact/Email/text()"/>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="'No Contact'"/>
                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                                    </Email>
                                    <Phone>
                                        <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when test="OpportunityContactRoles/records/Contact">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="OpportunityContactRoles/records/Contact/Phone/text()"/>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="'No Contact'"/>
                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                                    </Phone>
                                    <Opportunities>
                                        <xsl:for-each select="key('contact2',concat(Account/@url, '|', OpportunityContactRoles/records/Contact/@url))[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('recordid3', concat(Account/@url, '|', OpportunityContactRoles/records/Contact/@url, '|', Id))[1])]">
                                            <Opportunity>
                                                <Id>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="Id"/>
                                                </Id>
                                                <Name>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="Name/text()"/>
                                                </Name>
                                                <CreatedDate>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="CreatedDate/text()"/>
                                                </CreatedDate>
                                                <Amount>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="Amount/text()"/>
                                                </Amount>
                                                <StageName>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="StageName/text()"/>
                                                </StageName>
                                                <ClosedDate>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="CloseDate/text()"/>
                                                </ClosedDate>
                                                <ProjectState>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="Project_State__c/text()"/>
                                                </ProjectState>
                                                <SubProjectType>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="Sub_Project_Type__c/text()"/>
                                                </SubProjectType>
                                                <ProjectType>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="Project_Type__c/text()"/>
                                                </ProjectType>
                                                <ProjectCity>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="Project_City__c/text()"/>
                                                </ProjectCity>
                                            </Opportunity>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </Opportunities>
                                </Contact>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </Contacts>
                    </Account>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Accounts>
        </Aitor>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```